# List of tuples in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, tuples

I have a list of labels and a list of values in my views, where the nth element in the first list corresponds to the nth element of the second list , I want to display them in order in my template, in a list or a tab , for example :

```
- label1 : text1 
- label2 : text2 ..
```

To do so, I zipped the two lists :

```
labels = []
texts = [] 
#function that fills the lists.
values = zip(labels,results)
context = {'values': values }  
return render(request,'mypage.html',context)
```

Then in my template I have tried this :

```
{% for value in values %}
<ul>
<li> {{value}}.</li>
</ul>
```

But this renders a page with:

- ('label1', 'text1')
- ('label2', 'text2')

I have also tried to have a dictionary with the labels as keys and texts as values, it renders fine, but then the order is not respected since it's a dict. Ihave thought of other ways of doing it, such as having two dictionaries on for the first row and another for the second row, but my since my knowledge in python and django's templates is not consistent enough I don't know how to do this.

If anyone can help, would be much appreciated.

EDIT : Actually I found the answer two minuts after asking this, but I'll leave it in case it  could help anyone. In the template, I just did :

```
{% for labels, texts in values %}
<ul>
<li> {{labels}} : {{texts}}.</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `str.join`:

```
values = [" : ".join(x) for x in zip(labels,results)]
```

And pass this list to template.

With just `zip` you need to do unpacking inside the template:

```
values = zip(labels,results)

{% for label, text in values %}
<ul>
<li> {{ label }} : {{ text }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That was quick thank you, I edited my question,since I found the answer before I saw yours, but do you think I should keep it that way or use str.join instead ?

Comment: @sarahm That depends, if your using the same list in different templates( or multiple times in same template) then it's better to keep such logic at one place(in views file with str.join), because in case for example you need to change `:` to something else then you've to change it at multiple places but with `str.join` inside views file you just need to change it at one place. 
But, if you're doing to it only once then there's nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: @sarahm Also if you're zipping more than just two items(`zip(foo, bar, spam, eggs)`) then too much unpacking will look ugly, `str.join` is better in that case.